# Dynamic Usercontrol preservation on Async postback

Tags: asp.net, ajax, user-controls, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I've a control that dynamically loads other user controls.  Upon Async postback from one of the child user controls i'm reloading the session cached version of the child control.  However the page_load of this user control is not called when this occurs.

As a result there can be no event handling of this control.  Presumably there is a better way to store the controls and subsequently load them.  How would i do this?

**Edit** 
follow up question and solution here: [Dynamic usercontrol postback initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537910/dynamic-usercontrol-postback-initialization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the dynamic controls normally on the postback, the ViewState will hook up the events for you once the dynamic usercontrol is back in the control tree.

Comment: The controls after being 're-added' to the update panel do not appear to have their page_load/init functions called.  Presumably because they were cached.  

The Id's however are identical.  Thoughts?