# Dynamic usercontrol postback initialization

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have a user control that loads other user controls dynamically.  The issue is that on postback my controls don't exist.  Now i'm under the impression i have to re-initialize them.

Now to do this since they're UserControls and use the ascx file none of the UserControl's controls have been initialized in the empty constructor.

**Question:** How do i load the UserControl's ascx file at this time?

Currently i'm trying to do it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    Control ctrl;
    if(ctrlCollectionType.Rows[i]["Type"] is UserControl)
        ctrl = LoadControl((string)ctrlCollectionType.Rows[i]["Path"]);
    else
        this.LoadControl(ctrlCollectionType[i]["Type"], null);

    ctrl.ID = i;
    pnlContent.Controls.Add(ctrl);
}
```

Where ctrlCollectionType is the Type of the userControl.

**Edit:** Solution as per Joel Coehoorn's input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do two steps:

- Load the control (your `this.LoadControl()` call does this)
- Add the loaded control to your form's `Controls` collection.  You didn't show any code that does this.

Additionally, you need to do this *before* viewstate is restored in the page life cycle, or things won't work as you expect.  Since viewstate is restored before the Page_Load event fires, that means you need to do it on Page_Init or earlier.

Comment: Ahh you would be correct, out of curiosity from a best practices standpoint what would be the best way of preserving the ID of the control?

Comment: ClientID or just normal server-side id? If it's server ID, then just make sure you set it in the same way on the postback that you did when you created it.

Comment: Well the issue is that the user is able to choose the controls that are added dynamically so i can't count on creating it the same way.

Comment: You have to remember what they chose last time.